# Codeigniter CRUD - Records updated in the database but not showing on page

Tags: php, codeigniter, cache-control, grocery-crud

I am using Grocery CRUD in codeigniter for displaying records. When I edit and update one particular record then it is getting updated in the database but when I come back to list - updated records are not showing. I need to refresh page to see updated records.

Is there anything I am missing in the configuration? or is it a cache problem ?

Note - I am using datatable theme of grocery crud.

FYI - If I refresh page for displaying records then updated record display but when I edit that particular record again then previous value comes which was before editing.

Comment: Can you paste some code here. You must have written your fetching data code before the update code. Check it.

Comment: it is working on my local but when I am using https on server then it is not working. Let me check my code w.r.t your comment

Comment: Hi @Dipak , I am using datatable theme of grocery crud which does all this functionality automatic. I am using render function -  $this->grocery_crud->render();
 which returns all records. Do I need to check anything apart from this?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. But without physical reference it is hard to say what is the problem

Comment: FYI - If I refresh page for displaying records then updated record display but when I edit that particular record again then previous value comes which was before editing.